# Summernote loading textarea inside editor

Tags: javascript, laravel, summernote

I'm using Summernote.js but when it loads it's opening the textarea inside the editor itself

```
{!! Form::label('description', 'Body:', ['class' => 'control-label', 'style' => 'padding-top: 10px']) !!}
{!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'summernote']) !!}
```

Which gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9yL9.png)

All suggestions appreciated - this is really bugging me

Comment: do you see any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla stupidly had the css saved in the wrong asset folder - overlooked. thanks for you help!

Comment: please add an answer to this question. It might be useful to somebody else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues may be at hand.

1. The CSS file is a requirement.
2. Make sure it is in the correct folder.

If you are having issues with HTML being printed in Laravel, ensure you're calling in `{!! !!}` tags, rather than `{{ }}`.